# Trouble creating array

Tags: php

I have a problem…
I am trying to create an array from a mysql table.
But I don’t know how to format the data coming out of MySQL into an array in php.
Here is what I have done so far...

```
//Generate Org Data
$result_org = mysql_query("SELECT emp_no,sup_empno,Name,Title FROM employees");
// Initializes a container array 
$orgArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_org, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $currempno = $row['emp_no'];
    $currsupervisor = $row['sup_empno'];
    $currtitle = $row['Name']. '\n ' .$row['Title'];
```

**//   This is where I haven't a clue to get it the right format...??**

```
// Stores each database record to an array

      $buildorg = array("$currempno","$currsupervisor","$currtitle");

    // Adds each array into the container array
        array_push($orgArray, $buildorg);

        }
    // show the data to verify

        echo ($orgArray);


// the data needs to be exactly like this below
```

**o.addNode(003, 002, '', 'Jane Doe\nAsst Manager');**

> where 003 is the $currempno  002 is the $currsupervisor Jane Doe\nAsst
>   Manager is $currtitle

getting the o.addNode( along with the commas and double quotes  and ending ); 
around this has me perplexed

Any help would be appreciated…

K Driscoll

Comment: well the answers are same, so they are correct :D

Comment: @SharikovVladislav They are not necessarily correct - they are just the same - but are they answering the OP's question?

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like OP's mistake. I mean `o.addNode...` path. Let OP will clarify it, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are actually trying to create line

```
o.addNode(003, 002, '', 'Jane Doe\nAsst Manager');
```

so just put the values into the string and format it the way you want to - there is no need to create another array - you can create final strings and push those into the array:

```
$currempno = $row['emp_no'];
$currsupervisor = $row['sup_empno'];
$currtitle = $row['Name']. '\n ' .$row['Title'];

$output = sprintf("o.addNode(%03d, %03d, '', '%s');", $currempno, $currsupervisor, $currtitle);
array_push($orgArray, $output);
```

Comment: that worked great.. I have one issue though.. when I crete the file on the server that runs this... it is html so when I put in $orgarray where it needs to be in the code... the file is created all is see is the word ARRAY ... if I put in print_r($orgArray); I am seeing the references also i.e [0]  I just cant get the array only..

Comment: @user2135974 I don't think I understand what you're saying. What do you mean by "get the array only"?

Comment: I was expecting the array to be each record but there are keys included ie [0] I just wanted the array values one after another I tried using json encode but that adds a [ in front and it separates the records with ";".  There has to be a way to just return the array the way it was created

Comment: The keys come as part of `print_r` output.  Instead of using `print_r` to output the results, use `echo implode('<br/>', $orgArray);`

Comment: Thank you so much... I have it working now, just had to remove the <br/> and replaced with a space.  GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are look for, more or less:

```
$finalArray = array();
$result_org = mysql_query("SELECT emp_no,sup_empno,Name,Title FROM employees");
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_org, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
  $finalArray[] = array(
    $row['emp_no'],
    $row['sup_empno'],
    $row['Name'].'\n'.$row['Title']
  );
}
print_r($finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `array_push` function, better use another construction: `$someArray[] = $newElement;` — it has to do same. Example below.

This code will work:

```
//Generate Org Data
$result_org = mysql_query("SELECT emp_no,sup_empno,Name,Title FROM employees");
// Initializes a container array 
$orgArray = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_org, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $currempno = $row['emp_no'];
    $currsupervisor = $row['sup_empno'];
    $currtitle = $row['Name']. '\n ' .$row['Title'];

    $orgArray[] = array($currempno, $currsupervisor, $currtitle);
}

var_dump($orgArray);
```